# How to programmatically control which plot to display with LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting

LogLinearPlot is capable of plotting multiple functions in the same graph.

ex. `LogLinearPlot[{graph1[w], graph2[w]}, {w, 1, 100}]`

Is there a way to select automatically whether both `graph1` and `graph2` are executed? The reason is that in my code, I have certain conditions under which graph1 and/or graph2 would actually exist. In the case where one of the graphs does not exist, I get problems with the plotting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version you are using? in V10  this will works fine: g1[w_] := Erf[w]; LogLinearPlot[{g1[w], g2[w]}, {w, 1, 100}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure that in the invalid region the function doesn't evaluate to anything numerical.  For example,

```
Plot[{If[x < 0.5, Sin[x]], If[x > -0.5, x^2]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a plot is empty or not with

> FullForm[expr]

```
ploA = Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}];    
ploB = Plot[{Cos[]}, {x, -1, 1}];    
FullForm[ploB]
```

[image]

```
ploB[[1]] == {}
(* True *)
```

With this Strategy you can check if your plots are empty:

```
ploA = Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]] == {}
(* False *)

ploB = Plot[{Cos[]}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]] == {}
(* True *)
```

As shown by @Szabolcs You can use the If statement and control plots according to your needs:

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x]
f2[x_] := Cos[x]
Plot[{If[ploA == False, f1[x]], If[ploB == False, f2[x]]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
ploB = Plot[{Cos[x]}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]] == {}
(* False *)

Plot[{If[ploA == False, f1[x]], If[ploB == False, f2[x]]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]